# NightmareJS: How to block loading resources?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am making a small scraper with nightmareJS but loading all the external resources takes ages and consumes tons of bandwidth.

How can I only load the basic page html (without images, css etc)?

I couldn't find any relevant information online, maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 9):

like this :)

```
const nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: true,
    webPreferences: {
        images: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked for me!  Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Can you tell me where you found that information? The official documentation doesn't mention it but it works. Really awesome!

Comment: @MatthisKohli nightmare used electron as a browser. so I found this on electron doc or somewhere related to it.

Comment: `webPreferences` object is detailed here: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions

There's too many options for me to copy here in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md#seswebrequest) in tandem with Nightmare's `.action()` to filter content.

You might want to check out [`nightmare-load-filter`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-load-filter) (disclaimer: I'm the author), I believe that does what you're looking to do.